# File.AppendAllText is outputting different text than what the sting is

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, logging

I am confused because there seems to be an issue with what the console is logging and what the text that is being written to the file is.

I am writing to a log file the date time and then the string "test" hard coded value test. The file output ends up looking like "04-05-202016:52:06: Ae0A". As you can see in the code it takes in the log value not the hard coded. But I passed through test and the output is above.

How is it converting test to Ae0A? The Code for the write log is below. Note that  the WriteLine has the correct string in the output.

```
public static void writeLog(string log, string appendedFileName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(log);
        //get date
        string file_location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["log_file_location"];
        string file_name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[("log_file_name")];
        //We will make the folder location for the logs. This will be by date. 
        file_location += DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        file_location += "\\";
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(file_location);
        File.AppendAllText(@file_location + appendedFileName + file_name, DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ": " + "test" + Environment.NewLine), Encoding.UTF8);
    }
```

Comment: There is a typo in the text  that you want to write. I suppose that you want to write the date, then the time, but to do so you need to close the parenthesys after the date format

Comment: Thank you so much!! Such a simple mistake and you found it.

Comment: @TroyReynolds also instead of + between `Today....` and `Now...` you can just do `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm:ss")`